# Looking for a site that suggest a destination for group traveling from multiple countries

Tags: flight-search-engines, destinations, group-travel

We are a group of friends living in different countries. We'd like to find a way to choose a fair destination that minimizes the travel costs for everyone.

Sure, we can pick one place arbitrarily and everyone will fly to that destination. However, that might not be the optimal solution in terms of cost, as flight prices between different destinations can vary drastically.

Is there a site where one could set a list of origin countries and receive a list of potential destinations that are relatively cheap and convenient for all members of the group?

Comment: People are voting to close as "too broad"? Why? If such as website exists, an answer could be as short as "You can do this at `thiswebsite.com`." I doubt such a website exists but it's possible.

Comment: There is such a site, I'm pretty sure I used it several years ago. I found a site that offers this functionality but I think it's broken and I wasn't able to get any results. See https://www.tripmatch.org